# Guava Striped creation

Tags: java, guava

Why Google Guava `Striped` class doesn't contains factory methods that takes as arguments `Supplier<Lock>`(`Supplier<Semaphore>`, `Supplier<ReadWriteLock>`) intsance ?

For example I want to use CycleDetectingLockFactory for Lock creation but I can't:

```
final CycleDetectingLockFactory lockFactory = CycleDetectingLockFactory.newInstance( CycleDetectingLockFactory.Policies.THROW );    
//...
Striped<Lock> cycleDetectingLocks = Striped.lazyWeakLock( 64, new Supplier<Lock>()
{
        public Lock get()
        {
            return lockFactory.newReentrantLock( "" );
        }
    }; );
```

Comment: Could you create a new issue (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/entry) requesting this and explaining why you want it?

Answer (score 0):

It currently has a private constructor with just that signature.  Maybe they will make it public in a future version (or provide a factory method).  I can't think of a reason why not.  In the mean time you could probably achieve the same thing by creating a Stripped subclass and instantiating it directly.  Looks like each of the existing concreted Striped implementations are only about 20 lines. (most logic is in the base class)